# Python Multiprocessing with Input for Once

Tags: python, sql, input, multiprocessing

I like to query sql-db with 10 Process in multiprocess with the input provided. However, python asks the input 10 times. Is there any way to get input for once and use it in 10 Process ?

Example;

```
import concurrent.futures
import functools
from multiprocessing import Pool
import datetime
import time
import funcs
import mana
import os
import queries

base = os.getcwd()
kon = input('what is the kon?')
diz = input('what is the diz?')
ilk = input('what is the ilk?')
son = input('what is the son?')

bilgi = mana.get_info(base_path=base, konu=kon, dizin=diz, ilktarih=ilk, sontarih=son)

sorgu = queries.normal.format(
        path=bilgi['path'],
        konu=bilgi['konu'],
        ilktarih=bilgi['ilktarih'],
        sontarih=bilgi['sontarih'],
    )

def f1(sor, hast):
    print(f"{len(hast)} process will be created")
    pool = Pool(processes=len(hast))
    pool.imap_unordered(functools.partial(funcs.get_data_sqlalchemy, q=sor), hast)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HAST = ['dba', 'dbb', 'dbc', 'dbd', 'dbe', 'dbf', 'dbg', 'dbh', 'dbk', 'dbm']
    f1(sor=sorgu, hast=HAST)
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where it asks for user input

Comment: sorry I've added the inputs. This is just an example though. I wonder the logic

Comment: As the documentation says, ANYTHING that should only be executed once needs to be in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.  Remember, every subprocess reads and executes your script again from the beginning.

Comment: hmmm. I did not know that Tim. That is great. I've placed inputs in main bit and working perfectly now. Thanks a lot mate !

Comment: If you are just doing SQL queries in `funcs.get_data_sqlalchemy` multithreading might be a better option. Change `from multiprocessing import Pool` to `from mulitprocessing.dummy import Pool` and compare performance (and you do not have to worry that statements at global scope will be executed more than once).